# Eclipse: How to create Quick-Assist for If-else to Switch

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

In Eclipse Juno we have a [Quick-Assist](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-java-editor-quickassist.htm) for converting `Switch to If-else`. Is there a way to add a Quick-Fix or similar shortcut for the opposite action: converting `If-else to Switch` ?

For example convert:

```
if (kind == 1) {
  return -1;
} else if (kind == 2) {
  return -2;
} else {
  return 0;
}
```

To:

```
switch (kind) {
  case 1: return -1;
  case 2: return -2;
  default: return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. If it's possible to add a quick-fix for converting `if-else` to `switch`, then how would the Assist convert `if-else` statements with `boolean` expression that contain more than one variable to `switch` statement ?

Let's say, we want to convert this `if-else` statement to `switch`:

```
if (x == 1 && y == 1) {
   //do something
} else if (x == 1 && y == 3) {
   //do something else
} else if (x == 2 && y == 1) {
   //and so on.
}
```

This would result in:

```
switch (x) {
   case 1 : {
      switch (y) {
         case 1: // do something
         case 3: // and so on  
      }
      break;
   }
   case 2 : {
      switch (y) {
         case 1: //do something else
      }
      break;
   }
}
```

Personally, I wouldn't like to convert `if-else` with more complex `boolean` statements to `switch`, because the generated code could be very difficult to read and (maybe) wouldn't meet some Good Practices conventions. In simplier cases, like the one you've posted, it's not very difficult and wouldn't take so much time and effort for you to convert it.